# Subclassing in Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, swift, storyboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

When I override `func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)`, I get the destination view controller via

```
let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! VehicleDetailViewController
```

Works fine so far.

But how can I substitute `VehicleDetailViewController` with some subclass of `SomeDetailViewController`, e.g. `CarDetailViewController` or `BikeDetailViewController`?

So the code (snippet) should look like

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SegueID" {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let vehicle = Vehicle[indexPath.row]
        switch vehicle {
        case is Car:
            let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! CarDetailViewController

        case is Bike:
            let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! BikeDetailViewController
        }
    }
}
```

but Xcode tells me that the cast is not allowed:

> Could not cast value of type 'SomeApp.VecicleDetailViewController'
>   (0x10ede2220) to 'SomeApp.CarSensorDetailViewController'
>   (0x10ede2310).

Also help in Objective-C is welcome, because the question is not language-related.

Comment: why dont u try case 0, case 1 instead of objects ?

Comment: It is not about the switch-case (it works fine), the problem is the cast from `VehicleDetailViewController` to its subclass `CarDetailViewController`.

Comment: can u post the code that is related to error ? i.e code with CarSensorDetailViewController

Comment: Yes, I did add the Xcode error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A segue instantiates a specific class.  If you want multiple subclasses of `SomeDetailViewController` then you will need to layout multiple viewControllers in your Storyboard and create multiple segues.

You can do this by <kbd>control</kbd>-dragging from the *viewController* icon at the top of your viewController to each viewController that is a subclass of `SomeDetailViewController`.  Then add identifiers to the segues and call them with `performSegueWithIdentifier` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Another way to do this would be to create multiple prototype cells for your tableView, with each one wired to the specific viewController it is segueing to.

Comment: I really hoped there is another solution but this, but thanks to your answer.

Comment: I hoped for a code-only solution without Storyboard, but ok, Storyboard, here I come. :)

Comment: For a code only solution, abandon segues altogether and do it the old fashioned way.  Instantiate the new view controller, fill it in with the info it needs and push it.